# Javascript: How to Iterate Object [Key: value] but skip some keys ([fastest way possible])

Tags: javascript, object, key, iteration

If given a script like:

```
 <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Test DOC</title>

<script type="text/javascript" src="../nt_scr/jq_1.9.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

 var mainObj = { 0: {   "fruitName":"Lemon",
                        "fruitColor":"green",    
                        "fruitTaste":"bad"},

                 1:  {  "fruitName":"Mango",
                        "fruitColor":"Yellow",    
                        "fruitTaste":"Yammy"},
                 2:   {


                        "fruitName":"Banana",
                        "fruitColor":"Yellow",    
                        "fruitTaste":"Yammy"},


                "skip_these":   

                     {
                        "team1":"Liverpool",
                        "team2":"Manchester United"

                        } 

}

var collect_data = $.parseJSON(JSON.stringify(mainObj)),
    getFruitNames=[],getFruitColors=[], getFruitTastes=[];

$.each( collect_data,function(index,val){

     //console.log(val); //Un-comment this console.log to see the contents of 'val'

    //----->Here is the Challenge:,---------\\\
    if(/*How do you SKIP if val is something like */ "val.team1" || "val.team2"){

     getFruitNames.push(val.fruitName);
     getFruitColors.push(val.fruitColor);
     getFruitTastes.push(val.fruitTaste);

        //This works well so long as we have not yet reached the "skip_these":   
        //Once there, it reports an error because there is no "skip_these".fruitName or    "skip_these".fruitColor
        }

        console.log( getFruitNames[index])// Run a test out put :: NOTICE the "Undefined" in the Console. How to avoid that? 
        //To see well, Comment the previous console.log  <<the one on top>>
     })


</script>
</head>

<body>


</body>
</html>
```

I did this sometimes ago but somehow, my brain is just blank now.... Any suggestion is highly appreciated. (Please Run with your `jQuery`)

Comment: what is the logic of skipping some `keys`? Which keys should be skipped and which shouldn't?

Comment: You can skip an iteration in $.each by returning true

Comment: If you run the CODE, NOTICE the `"Undefined"` in the Console.

Comment: @DanielHigueras... jQuery documentation (http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/) says : `jQuery.each( array, callback )` where do you put the `true` .... any example??

Comment: @ErickBest "Returning non-false is the same as a continue statement in a for loop; it will skip immediately to the next iteration." Taken from your link

Comment: @DanielHigueras.. I added `return true` inside the `if` it just stopped and `NO OUT-PUT` in the `console`... I added `return true` inside the `$.each`  but outside the `if` still get `undefined` values

Comment: @ErickBest See if my answer solves what you need

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [JQuery docs](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/) state,

> Returning non-false is the same as a continue statement in a for loop;
>   it will skip immediately to the next iteration.

So, following your example, you can skip the objects with the properties you don't need by using the following:

**JavaScript**

```
$.each( collect_data,function(index,val){

     //console.log(val); //Un-comment this console.log to see the contents of 'val'

    //----->Here is the Challenge:,---------\\\
    if(val.team1 || val.team2){
      return true;
    }

     getFruitNames.push(val.fruitName);
     getFruitColors.push(val.fruitColor);
     getFruitTastes.push(val.fruitTaste);

        //This works well so long as we have not yet reached the "skip_these":   
        //Once there, it reports an error because there is no "skip_these".fruitName or    "skip_these".fruitColor


        console.log( getFruitNames[index])//No "Undefined"
     })
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/9vOACIpnlWRtSWjmAm5x?p=preview

Answer (score 1):

(not jquery - vanilla)
Iterate properties and skip specific keys: (did not test for syntax but it should be ok)

```
    var skipped = ['keySkipped'];
    for (var someProperty in someObject) {
        if (someObject.hasOwnProperty(someProperty) && skipped.indexOf(someObject[someProperty] === -1)) {
            // do stuff
        }
    }
```

Explanation: iterate properties and if propertie indeed is contained by the object but not contained in `skiped` do whatever

Comment: JQuery is just an library on top on JS (often referenced Vanilla), as result you can anywhere you have an object. - I will change some names to amke it clearer for you

Comment: Thanks.... I really wanna use the `$.each` though... Changing to `vanila` would mean digging through over **180** different `scripts` in different `directories` to change the `$.each` to the `vanila` approach... that's gonna be another monumental task on its own ... Thanks though!

Comment: Np makes sense , though you can use my code under  each :p